# How to use regex to match strings that don't contain special characters (&, \, <, >, |, ) unless they are proceeded by a backslash

Tags: c++, regex, string, flex-lexer, regex-negation

Right now I am using `[^ \\&<>|\t\n]+` which will match any string that contains characters that are not a space, \, &, <, >, |, \t, \n. What I want to do is also allow you to escape any of these special characters so that (for example) \< or \& would still allow my entire string to be matched.

**Should match:**

`abcdefghijk
abcdef\&hdehud\<jdow\\`

**Should not match:**

`abcdefhfh&kdjeid
abcdjedje\idwjdj`

I found this pattern `([^\[]|(?<=\\)\[)+` which does the same thing for just the "[" character. I couldn't figure out how to extend this to apply to any additional characters.

Any idea how I can make the exception for characters preceded by a backslash?

If it makes any difference, I'm using this in Flex and C++ to tokenize a string for a shell. I believe I need to use negative look-behinds but I don't know how to do that with multiple characters.

Comment: On the one hand, you say `What I want to do is also allow you to escape any of these special characters`, which would seem to also require spaces to be escaped. On other hand, you also say `So valid strings would be: abcdefghijk abcdef\&hdehud\ `., where the space isn't escaped.

Comment: Sorry, fixed now! Those were supposed to be separate strings, not a string with a space in it.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/PeFm8A/1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are already most of the way to the answer:

You are using the negated set `[^ \\&<>|\t\n]` to specifiy which characters may not be present, so all you have to do is then use the same set without the negation preceded by a `\` to escape the character. That gets you this `\\[ \\&<>|\t\n]` which can be read as "a `\` followed by any one of the items in the set" now combine the two and you get `([^ \\&<>|\t\n]|\\[ \\&<>|\t\n])+`.

To break it down:

One or more of: `[^ \\&<>|\t\n]` or `\\[ \\&<>|\t\n]`

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks so much! I was trying to over complicate it by using an or with each individual special character in my negation but couldn't get it to work. This solution is simple and makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 2):

As usual, using a regular expression here is overkill. This is a simple text search:

```
const std::string target = "\\&<>|";
std::string iter = str.find_first_of(target);
while (iter != str.end()) {
    if (*iter != '\\')
        found_bad_character(*iter);
    iter = str.find_first_of(target, std::next(iter));
}
```

Comment: This is used in Flex as a lexer for a shell so I needed the regex to specify my token but in other cases I could see your solution being helpful!